# How to make a tooltip for a chart in d3?

Tags: d3.js

[image]

We need to make it move like here.[example](https://observablehq.com/@connor-roche/multi-line-chart-focus-context-w-mouseover-tooltip) The code is complex there, I can't figure it out.

I wrote the code [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-galileo-t9c1i), but I don’t understand how to make the tooltip move horizontally not behind the mouse, but near the nearest horizontal mark (as in the example)

It is not yet clear where the text above the bold text in the tooltip comes from. How to remove it so that it looks like in the picture?

How do I make the title of the tooltip match the label on the X-axis?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. The way I typically do this is to create a series of SVG elements -- such as circles or rects -- using the same scale and data as the paths.

You can make these objects visible or invisible. Either way, you can attach mouseenter, mouseleave events to each to render and populate the tooltip.